# Creating categories that are dynamically driven by filters

Tags: category, ce-1.9.0.1

I’m working on an automotive parts based site and I’m trying to determine the best way to achieve the following.  Every part we have is specific to make/model.  What I want to do is create a finder that lets you drill down by year, make, model and submodel.  I’ve found an extension from Amasty to do this but the one thing I’m not finding is the ability to dynamically create category URL’s based on these filters.

For example if I have a 2013 Ford Mustang GT I’d like to be able to have a category landing page at http://www.example.com/2013-Ford-Mustang-GT which contains a listing of all relevant parts which is organized by a templated heiarchy.  For example all categories will have a structure that includes categories such as Suspension, Aero, Exhaust, etc.

Any suggestions on how to best tackle this?

Comment: Does this solve it for you? https://github.com/ho-nl/layered-landing

Comment: @PaulHachmang that's a good first start i'll have to install it later to see how it works.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can give [this extension](https://github.com/tzyganu/rule-products) a try.
It allows you to create pages that list products based on rules.
The rules are similar to magento's catalog discount rules.
So you can create a page with the url `2013-Ford-Mustang-GT` (yes, the extension supports url rewrites) with the rule

```
All of these conditions are true:
  year = 2013
  make = Ford
  model = Mustang-GT
```

Then you will see in the page all the products that match this rule.
You will also have a layered navigation available that works in the exact same way as the default layered navigation works.
You will be able to filter the products by category and by any other attribute you marked to be used in the layered navigation.

More details about what the extension does, complete with screenshots, or how to use it [can be found here](https://github.com/tzyganu/rule-products/wiki)